# node js resize png doesnt work on aws lambda only

Tags: node.js, sharp

```
        var newImage = await sharp(originalBuffer).resize(newWidth, newHeight, {
            fit: sharp.fit.inside,
            withoutEnlargement: true
        });
        console.log(`after resize before to buffer ${typeof newImage} `, newImage)

        // works on localhost mac but not on aws lambda
        // https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2085#issuecomment-587187740        
        newImage = await newImage.toBuffer();
```

the error is
`Error: undefined Input buffer contains unsupported image format Error: Input buffer contains unsupported image format`

using `express-fileupload` for files uploading. don't think it's relevant here. also tried `multer`

I've researched a lot and haven't found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but if the lambda function linked with api gateway, before the run the sharp you need to see with console log when sending data to function. Is it coming undefiend or same as your data ? Sometimes we cant get the Api gateway request body from function. Try to send with application/json header or form data.